# get Region name in a variable when some Region is clicked using Google Geo Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-visualization

I am implementing Google Geo Map, what i am trying to do is that e.g if i click `US` on the map i would get name of the country as alert(e.g if i click US, i must get US as alert), which i can eventually use as a variable. When i try to loop over the selected Div i get

> (`Undefined`) as alert

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
     google.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i am trying to fetch elements with in `chart_div` element.

```
 jQuery('#chart_div').on('click', function(){
                    jQuery(this).children().each(function () {
                       alert(this.value);

                    });
                });
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use a jQuery event handler - the Visualization API has built-in event handling that will do this:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length) {
        alert(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
    }
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: i am getting this error `TypeError: google.visualization.events.addlistener is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, that should be `addListener`, not `addlistener`.  I'll fix my answer.